# How do you write long division of a multivariable polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

It is clear that when you have two polynomials f and g, there exist uniquely determined polynomials q and r such as $f=qg+r$ (1), where $\deg{r}\leq \deg{g}$.

But how do you extend this theorem for polynomials such as $f(x,y)$ which are being divided to $g(x,y)$ and also what if the two poynomials were $f(x,y,z)$ and $g(x,y,z)$.

This is what I mean: For example, let $f(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+y^3-x^2-y^2-z^2$ and $g(x,y,z)=xy+yz+zx$. If you divide $f$ to $g$ then would there hold a relation similar to (1)? What if the polynomials were arbitrary?

After writing the general statement, could you also provide an example for some specific polynomials, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is it clear what I want to understand now?

Comment: Yes, thank you!  Now, I'm curious about the answer too.  ^_^

Comment: You may want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316752/division-algorithm-for-multivariate-polynomials or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order